# plot least squared line in a scatter plot

Tags: plot, pandas, scatter

Having created a scatter plot with pandas. I don't know how to create the regresion line that would be the least squared from the points.
looking for examples in http://matplotlib.org i haven't found any similar graph.

Thanks you a lot in advance !!

Answer (score 5):

Pandas has an [ordinary least squares (`ols`)](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/computation.html#standard-ols-regression) function, there is a very detailed example in [the 0.10.1 docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.10.1/computation.html#standard-ols-regression) of how to plot the result, here's a snippet:

```
model = ols(y=rets['AAPL'], x=rets.ix[:, ['GOOG']], window=250)
# just plot the coefficient for GOOG
model.beta['GOOG'].plot()
```

[image]

*Note: this example is no longer in the docs (since 0.10.1), I'm not sure why.*

Comment: That docs link no longer contains the snippet. And when I do `model.beta['GOOG']` the result is simply a number! (tw. I'm not just picking holes in historical answers. A Google search brought me here!)

Comment: @LondonRob You can look back in history: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.10.1/computation.html#standard-ols-regression very strange if this no works. Will try and have a look later. Note: the window argument is critical, or you do just get a value.

Comment: Ah! Didn't realise the `window` argument was critical!